# How to get the log with the output of git describe

Tags: git, git-describe

I want to use  the output of `git describe` in my program so if a problem occurs, I can easily track down in what revision this happened.

The output is similar to: `v2.12-20-g22290d9`

I know I can `checkout` it easily, but how can I track the log with `git log` or a similar tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log v2.12-20-g22290d9` will show the log starting at that tag.

Comment: I swear it didn't work when I tried that. Anyway, now it does. Thanks :)